# Error in .java that cannot be resolved after changing in gradle android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, reflection

App works fine till yesterday but today when I opened the project, I get error only in .java

In a class, only in .java I get error as **unresolved error java.**

```
 intent = Intent(this@UserImageActivity, UserDetailsActivity::class.java)
```

I used invalidate cache and restart but still I couldn't resolve the compile error.

```
  build.gradle (app)

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
       }

     build.gradle (AppProject)

     buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
```

build.gradle (app)

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

[image]

Comment: Add a few points on where the error occurs, the error message and some code that can relate to the problem.

Comment: I checked many times,even I copied the code to other project but still the same error. wherever :class.java present, error showing

Comment: which word unresolved?

Comment: I have attached the captured screenshot @JohnJoe. unresolved reference java compile error.

Comment: I tried all ways. Even in Settings -> Plugs -> UnChecked kotlin and checked kotlin and restarted but still same.

Comment: @RamjiV - try invalidate cache and restart android studio. Click file options and then invalidate and restart.

Comment: I tried invalidate cache and restart but still the error is displaying :-( @TheAnkush

Comment: Try using lifecycle extensions ```implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"``` in your gradle file

Comment: After using lifecycle, I am able to run the app but still red error is displaying in.java. I am getting warning error in this line  androidList -> androidList.albumId.toString().equals(id) as Name shadowed: androidList
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin